# Asymmetric routing problems in LINUX

Tags: routing, iproute

**Asymmetric routing problems are driving me crazy!**

I am trying to build a multi-homed server with 3 NICs.  Each NIC is connected to 3 different subnets:

eth0:   LAN connected, 10.99.72.38; function: Management traffic
eth1:   LAN connected, 10.99.70.150; function: User traffic
eth2:   WAN connected, 10.99.74.85; function: User traffic

I am using an Amazon Linux image (Linux 3.14.20-20.44.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64) but I can switch to CentOS if it really makes a difference.

The functionality I am trying to implement:

**eth0: Management traffic**

- address: 10.99.72.38
- I want this to be an 'isolated' interface, only accepting and replying to addresses in 10.0.0.0/8
- Think of this as a 'ssh only from local LAN' NIC.
- Can ONLY respond back through eth0
- All other destinations are blocked, meaning, no other destinations can be reached through this interface
- WILL NOT use eth1 or eth2 for reply traffic for traffic arriving on eth0.

**eth1: User traffic to/from LAN**

- Address: 10.99.70.150
- accepts any user traffic from the LAN to any destination
- routes packets out through eth1 for traffic destined for 10.x.x.x.
- routes packets out through eth2 for any other destination (default route)
- will NOT route incoming packets through eth0

**eth2: User traffic to/from WAN**

- address: 10.99.74.85
- accepts any user traffic from eth1 and will send packets out eth2 for any destination not in 10.x.x.x
- accepts reply packets on eth2 and routes through eth1 for any traffic destined for 10.x.x.x
- will NOT route incoming packets through eth0

I have created a iproute2 table in rt_tables called 'mgmt' and added policy based routing rules with high priority to try and isolate this interface, but no matter what I try, the main routing table still seems to be called as eth0 is the default route. Problems include:

- Incoming packets from eth1 are routed through eth0 (I don't want this!)
- Incoming packets from eth2 destined for 10.x.x.x are routed through eth0 (I don't want this!)
- When I delete the default eth0 route from main, I lose eth0 functionality completely, even with a route in the mgmt table, but eth1 then replies correctly.

Starting from the beginning, the unmodified route table (route -n):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
0.0.0.0         10.99.72.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0  
0.0.0.0         10.99.70.1      0.0.0.0         UG    10001  0        0 eth1  
0.0.0.0         10.99.74.1      0.0.0.0         UG    10002  0        0 eth2  
10.99.70.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1  
10.99.72.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0  
10.99.74.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Unmodified IP rules are:

```
0:      from all lookup local  
32766:  from all lookup main  
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Any assistance in correctly formulating the specific routing rules, tables, and routes, and showing me what the final routing tables and rules would look like would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the netmask for the three interfaces? Are they connected to the same LAN?

Comment: Don't use the legacy `route` command, esp. if you're also using rules. Show `ip ro sh` output, `ip ru sh` output, and `ip ro sh table mgmt` output and the same for any other tables you may have created. You may also need `iptables` rules to prevent packets going out to eth0 that originated from eth1.

Comment: @HaukeLaging:  all three interfaces have a netmask of 255.255.255.0.  Each interface is on a different subnet.  Since this machine is being built on Amazon Web Services (AWS) within a single VPC, they share a common (virtual) VPC router.

Comment: Will all connections to `eth0` be from 10.99.72.x?

Comment: "accepts any user traffic from eth1" does not make sense to me. You must configure on `eth1` what is to be accepted. There is no internal routing between interfaces. Do I understand it right: `eth2` shall not accept new incoming connections at all? If you use `ip rule` then you should show us its output.

Comment: @HaukeLaging:  Connections on eth2 are not limited to 10.99.72.x.  Connections will be from a management network, which will extend beyond the 10.99.72.x subnet.

Comment: @HaukeLaging:   The intent of 'user traffic' was meant to imply that normal traffic flow would be "eth1 to/from eth2".  This path is expected to carry normal 'user' traffic.  eth0 would be dedicated to server management traffic (command and control, log collection, monitoring, ssh, etc)--no traffic from either eth1 or eth2 should ever be allowed to reach eth0 (and traffic from eth0 should never be allowed to reach either eth1 or eth2).  I hope this clarification helps.

Comment: If a new connection for the IP address of `eth0` arrives for whatever reason on `eth1` or `eth2` then you cannot prevent the kernel from "routing" the packet to `eth0` (because it is not real routing). You just can either throw it away (Netfilter / `iptables`) or prevent the system from answering (with input interface based policy routing) which prevents TCP connections but not one-way UDP (which shouldn't do harm though).

Comment: Most confusing is that `eth0` uses "10/8", and the other interfaces also use a 10.x.y.z network without telling the netmask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of the default gateway setting for `eth0` and `eth1`. How that is done depends on your distro.

You probably don't need policy routing. I guess what you want is best achieved with Netfilter / `iptables`.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 ! -s 10.99.72.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth0 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -o eth0 -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT 2 -i eth1 ! -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 3 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT 3 -i eth2 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 4 -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

That can probably be done without Netfilter but with policy routing instead.

Comment: Thanks for this approach.  I haven't spent much time using iptables, so I need to do a little homework to see if the above will do what I am hoping for.  Could you please clarify your last sentence? ---"That can probably be done without Netfilter but with policy routing instead."

Comment: @SteveT You talked about routing only thus I thought you might prefer a routing solution. You can set up a route of type `unreachable`, `blackhole`, `throw`, or `prohibit`. But as I said: In contrast to Netfilter that affects responses only.

Comment: I finally had a chance to go through the rules listed above...I like the approach of using this along with policy routing to solve the original problem.  Thank you very much for your help.